# Why textAlign of AutoSizeText Widget and crossAxisAlignment of Wrap Widget doesn't align correctly?

Tags: flutter, dart, text-alignment, autoresize

I'm using  a `Wrap` and  [AutoSizeText](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) for represent a value and the unit of measure on the same line.

I'm trying to align the value and the unit of measure at the end  of the `Container` but it doesn't happen and what I get is this:

[image]

Below I attach the code:

```
                          Wrap(
                            crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.end,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  height: calculatedHeight,
                                  child: AutoSizeText(
                                    val.toString() + ' ',
                                    minFontSize: 5,
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: item.textSize),
                                  )),
                              Container(
                                  color: Colors.amber,
                                  height: calculatedHeight,
                                  child: AutoSizeText(
                                    unit,
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                                    minFontSize: 5,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: item.unitSize),
                                  )),
                            ],
                          ),
```

if I remove the `Container` it obviously aligns correctly but the problem is that if I remove it, the text is not resized..

Comment: what's the point to use `Wrap` instead of `Row` here? and `alignment` not cross axis

Comment: @Nagual if I use `alignment: WrapAlignment.end,` nothing change and if I use `Row` the issue is the same

Comment: How exactly you want your UI to look ?

Comment: I would like that the value and the the unit of measure are aligned at  the bottom center of the `Container`

Comment: Which means, the one with green background ?

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan no, **6193.0** should be at the bottom center of the red `Container` and **rpm** should be at the  bottom center of the amber `Container`

Comment: Even without `Container()` it tends to work fine !

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan no, without the Container the Text isn't resized

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234779/discussion-between-ragu-swaminathan-and-nico).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely the problem is wrapping the `AutoSizeText` with the `Container`s, you can try this and replace the `Wrap` with the `Row` and wrap it with a `FittedBox`:

```
                            FittedBox(
                                fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                                child:
                                    Row(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                      children: [
                                        AutoSizeText(
                                          val.toString() + ' ',
                                          minFontSize: 1,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: item.textSize,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: HexColor(
                                              item.colors!.back!,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        AutoSizeText(
                                          unit,
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                                          minFontSize: 1,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: item.unitSize,
                                            color: HexColor(
                                              item.colors!.back!,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
```

Comment: ok thank you! now I try to use it , even if I would need the `Wrap` more